# How to pass baseUrl from protractor.conf into my test to assert it in tests?

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

What I want to do is:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(protractor.baseUrl + urls.cookiesPage());
```

This is what I get:

```
 - Expected 'https://somewebsite.com/about/cookies/' to equal 'undefined/about/cookies/'.
```

How to pass baseUrl from config file into my test so I can assert it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

5 minutes later, I found an answer... after 2 hours of research:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + 'some/url/right/here');
```

So, this was the answer:

```
browser.baseUrl
```

Comment: On my side this assertion throws an error:  *Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>'*, not on your side ?

Comment: the only note I can add is that browser.baseUrl returns a different value if you are debugging in vscode. When debugging you don't get a slash on the end, when running 'ng e2e' you do get one. I had to modify my tests accordingly.

Comment: How  do you set value  for baseurl in config.js ? I did like this but get a compile error . exports.config = {
  //directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  baseUrl='https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo',

Comment: I can pass it like this but I prefer to mention it in my config,js anyway to achieve it ? Thank you . protractor defaultconfig.js --baseUrl https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo